# Bootstrap Grid Doesn't work as expected

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-grid

I want my main content and Sidewidget in the same row. With my knowledge of bootstrap grid, I tried to make this work but the sidewidget is stacking below the content and not in the sides. Here is the required snippets.

**body.html**

```
<!-- Navigation -->
{% include 'nav.html' %}
<!-- Page Content -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 ">
      {% block content %}
      {% endblock %}
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
       {% block sidewidget %}
       {% endblock %}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/tinymce/custom.js' %}" ></script>
```

**nav.html**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Start Bootstrap</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home
            <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
        </li>
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'add' %}">Add Article</a>
          </li>  
        {% endif %}
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**My {% block content %}**

```
{% for post in posts %}
      <h2 class="mt-4">{{post.title}}</h2>
      <!-- Author -->
      <p class="lead">
        by
        <a href="/author/{{post.author}}">{{post.author}}</a>
      </p>
      <hr>
      <!-- Date/Time -->
      <p class="lead">Published on <b>{{post.published_date}}</b></p>
      <hr>
      <!-- Preview Image -->
      <img class="img-fluid" src="{{post.image.url}}" alt="Img Placeholder">
      <p>{{post.images}}</p>

      {% for tag in post.tags.all %}
      <p>{{tag.name}}</p>
      {% endfor %}
      <hr>
      <!-- Post Content -->
      <p class="lead">{{post.content|safe|truncatewords:"60"|linebreaks}}</p>
      <footer class="entry-footer">
        <a href="{{post.slug}}" class="btn-readmore"><button class="btn btn-primary">Read More</button></a>
      </footer>
      <hr>
{% empty %}
       <h1> Nothing to display</h1>
{% endfor %}  
{% endblock %}
```

**My {% Sidewidget %} block**

```
  <!-- Search Widget -->
  <div class="card my-4">
    <h5 class="card-header">Search</h5>
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">Go!</button>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Categories Widget -->
  <div class="card my-4">
    <h5 class="card-header">Categories</h5>
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <ul class="list-unstyled mb-0">
            <li>
              <a href="#">Web Design</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">HTML</a>
            </li>
            <li>  
              <a href="#">Freebies</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <ul class="list-unstyled mb-0">
            <li>
              <a href="#">JavaScript</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">CSS</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Tutorials</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Side Widget -->
  <div class="card my-4">
    <h5 class="card-header">Side Widget</h5>
    <div class="card-body">
      You can put anything you want inside of these side widgets. They are easy to use, and feature the new Bootstrap 4 card containers!
    </div>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

I have tried tweaking but nothing seems to work

I want the page like this:

```
|*****************************|  
|navigationbar                | 
|*****************************|
|Post1(Col1-Col8)  |SIDEWIDGET| 
|*****             |          |
|Post2(Col1-Col8)  |          |
|*****             |          |
|PostN(Col1-Col8)  |          |
|*****************************|
|Footer                       |
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work. The `col-lg-*` modifier applies only for screens that are over 1200px wide as per bootstrap's documentation. Maybe you're using a smaller screen and you also need to add the `col-sm` and `col-md` modifiers. Please try those and let me know if it works.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-lg-8 ">
      {% block content %}
      {% endblock %}
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
       {% block sidewidget %}
       {% endblock %}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: in your case the sidewidget will take up only the first row's column not the all the columns  in all rows the OP is askinig for spanning it through all the whole of 2nd columns spanning thorugh all rows

Comment: Not at all. If you look at the rest of his code, he is not adding more rows anywhere else.

Comment: there are already three rows and he wants to span the widget accross all the three rows in second column see the pic otherwise the question would have been very simple

Comment: Hi martin, I already tried what you mentioned, doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

you can't use a bootstarp grid system for it because the sidewidget is going to take up the column of the whole  three rows .You would have to use **flex box** for it. by using grid system columns can be individually used in different rows  but you cannot have a whole column spanning over the different rows .

Comment: Hi, I might have failed to explain, I want my side widget to be in between col-8 to col-12, on the right.

Comment: in grid its not possible but you have to use custom cs and html for it  by using flex

Comment: Thanks nikhil, I will try what you said.

Comment: i cant provide  you with full fledged code i tried but if you like the answer u can upvote it at best because it didnt gave you the whole solution so not asking to green tick it

Comment: I wish I could. I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: It says that votes of user with less than 15 reputations are recorded but not displayed on public platform. So yes, I upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the 'nav' section the 'nav' tag is not closed `</nav>`. close it and try again.
I think that will solve your problem.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Start Bootstrap</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home
            <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
        </li>
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'add' %}">Add Article</a>
          </li>  
        {% endif %}
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```